# Scripting C++ with python

Tags: c++, python

I have a C++ program and I want to implement scripts on it. The desired scenario is, I have an executable of c++ code, it then calls at specific times a python script so it knows what to do through the embeded interpreter and the script then uses some form of API from the c++ program. This is where I ran into a problem. To expose c++ code to python you need to compile a DLL of the wrappers that you want and load it as a module inside python and that breaks my intention of python accessing the **executable**'s functions.

Any way to resolve this problem without resorting to put so much pieces of c++ on a shared library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is to embed Python code into your application. There is an [article on python.org](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) on how to do that using raw CPython, but it's not that exhaustive when it comes to C++. A better bet might be to use [`Boost.Python`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/GettingStarted) or [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html).